Combine two columns into one new column pandas
I have a dataframe pulled from an excel/csv.
I rename two columns containing names into column Name1 and Name2
I wish to create a new column with the names from column Name1 and Name2



Name1
Name2




John
Joe


Kelly
Guy



I use concatenate into a new variable. When I print that variable, I indeed get the full concatenated list.
But when I export it out to a csv or excel and open it up, I am left with the new column I created (great) but it is completely blank. Why?
The exported excel/csv should look like so:



Name1
Name2
New




John
Joe
John


Kelly
Guy
Kelly




Joe




Guy



Here is my code:
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Arraytomodify.xlsx', index_col=0)

df.rename(columns={"Nome / Name": "Name1"}, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={"Nome / Name.1": "Name2"}, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={"Cognome / Nachname": "Lastname1"}, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={"Cognome / Nachname.1": "Lastname2"}, inplace=True)

# Append the data from 'Name1' column to Name2 and give data to combined variable
combined = pd.concat([df['Name1'], df['Name2']]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(combined)

#create 'new' column and dump combined variable into column
df['new'] = combined

df.to_excel('modificato2.xlsx')


read notice:[mre]

Can you provide an example of what you are expecting? do you want to combine the values from each column together? or just create a column with all the values from each column

Apologies added two tables demonstrating before and after.

melt and concat:
out = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True),
                 df.melt(value_name='New')['New']],
                axis=1)


Output:
   Name1 Name2    New
0   John   Joe   John
1  Kelly   Guy  Kelly
2    NaN   NaN    Joe
3    NaN   NaN    Guy


you need to convert the Series to a Dataframe and then concat them:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name1": ["John", "Kelly"],
    "Name2": ["Joe", "Guy"],
    })

out = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df['Name1'], df['Name2']])
      .reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()], axis=1)
      .rename(columns={0:'new'}


OUTPUT:
   Name1 Name2   new
0   John   Joe   John
1  Kelly   Guy  Kelly
2    NaN   NaN    Joe
3    NaN   NaN    Guy

If you do not want the NaN values you can use fillna()
out = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df['Name1'], df['Name2']])
      .reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()], axis=1)
      .rename(columns={0:'new'})
      .fillna(" ")

OUTPUT:
   Name1 Name2    new
0   John   Joe   John
1  Kelly   Guy  Kelly
2                 Joe
3                 Guy


Thank you very much for your assistance. Question I thought pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') converts the file given into a dataframe that you assign to a variable?

@PietroAretino yes it does, but when you are concatenating 2 Series, it will return a series hence why you need to convert the combined to a dataframe

Your combined series is too long. It has 8 elements, when the original dataframe has only 4 rows. The following should do what you're asking for:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name1": ["John", "Kelly", "", ""], "Name2": ["Joe", "Guy", "", ""]})

combined = pd.concat([df["Name1"], df["Name2"]]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(len(combined))  # 8

combined = (
    pd.concat([df["Name1"], df["Name2"]]).replace("", pd.NA).dropna(ignore_index=True)
)

df["New"] = combined
print(df)
#    Name1 Name2    New
# 0   John   Joe   John
# 1  Kelly   Guy  Kelly
# 2                 Joe
# 3                 Guy

